# BottomNavigationView height is not wrapped to the bottom

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I have a linear layout with a bottomNavigationView, the thing is that it does not has height and I dont know why

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_color"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**output**

[image: u]

If I for example put 100dp as height it expands from the bottom but I cant still see it

[image]

So the problem is that I cannot see my bottomview if I place it at the end of my linearlayout, any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding a relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainrlot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_color"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the position of layout at bottom, add this code. `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android: layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_color"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tried before asking the question but this does not solved my problem, thanks anyway